# Can I install MySQL ODBC Driver 8 on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: mysql, pyodbc, unixodbc, amazon-linux

I'm running into an issue when connecting to a MySQL database on Amazon Linux 2 using `pyodbc` and the `mysql-connector-odbc` driver. As shown below:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08004', "[08004] [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver]Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (2059) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I tried upgrading my Amazon Linux version to `2.0.20230207.0`, but got a similar error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08004', "[08004] [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver]Authentication plugin 'sha256_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/sha256_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (2059) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

My understanding is this is because the version of MySQL server is using a newer version than what my ODBC driver supports. I would love to upgrade the ODBC driver to validate this is the cause, but it seems that Amazon Linux only supports `mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.5` yet the latest version available is `8.0.32`. Is there any way to install the newer version of the MySQL ODBC driver manually, or is it just not possible with Amazon Linux 2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And a somewhat leftfield question for you: why mysql-odbc and pyodbc when there's pymysql? I'd assume that it performs better with fewer layers?

Comment: what error gives you when you try to install the latest version of the mysql connector?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-installation-binary-unix-tarball.html

Comment: @david-ao I get a missing dependency error when I try to install directly from the tarball using yum

Comment: which are the missing dependecies? You will probably will need to install those first, probably unixODBC

Answer (score 0):

i think you need create user and pwd for the mysql server

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

ref : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html

Comment: this would be changing the database settings to use the older MySQL password logic, right? I don't think that helps here. I want to connect to MySQL Server 8 dbs that use the new password logic

Comment: i think you can set the your existing `username` and `password` there,